# TypeScript Narrowing seemingly not working: Object is possibly undefined

Tags: typescript

Ok, so I am very new to TypeScript and I am confused about the **Object is possibly undefined** error in the following code (which has been highly abbreviated):

```js
interface IUrlData {
    wsPropertyNames: string[];
    routeValuesRegExp: RegExp;
}

export default class Builder implements IBuilder {
    private _urlData?: IUrlData;
    async build(): Promise<IConfig> {
        // VS Code Intellisense says that this._urlData is IUrlData | undefined in the next line.
        if (this._urlData) {
            // In this next line, VS Code Intellisense says this._urlData is IUrlData (no undefined, so narrowed by the if).
            this._urlData.wsPropertyNames.forEach((value) => {
                const obj = wjConfig[value];
                if (isConfig(obj)) {
                    // This is where the error happens.  All of the sudden, this._urlData is back to IUrlData | undefined.
                    makeWsUrlFunctions(obj, this._urlData.routeValuesRegExp);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

So, can anybody help me out either pointing me to my error or providing a workaround if this is something that TypeScript is messing due to a bug or similar?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix that assign `this._urlData` to a local variable and it should work. This is needed because Typescript cannot guarantee that `this._urlData` is not going to change in between async functions.

It's going to be like the following:

```js
interface IUrlData {
    wsPropertyNames: string[];
    routeValuesRegExp: RegExp;
}

export default class Builder implements IBuilder {
    private _urlData?: IUrlData;
    async build(): Promise<IConfig> {
        const urlData = this._urlData;
        if (urlData) {
            urlData.wsPropertyNames.forEach((value) => {
                const obj = wjConfig[value];
                if (isConfig(obj)) {
                    // This is where the error happens.  All of the sudden, this._urlData is back to IUrlData | undefined.
                    makeWsUrlFunctions(obj, urlData.routeValuesRegExp);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  It indeed fixes the issue. I still don't have it clear as to why is needed though, but I guess this is because I am so new to TypeScript.